# é showing up as &eacute in TextEdit

Tags: textedit

I am opening a text file using Mac's TextEdit that has `&eacute;` in it. `&eacute;` is supposed to be showing up as é instead.

Is there a way to make TextEdit read it as é?

Comment: Can't you just edit the file and replace the phrase with é, using copy/paste if necessary?

Comment: If you add the .html extension to your text file, it should display as é.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&eacute;` is one of the **HTML** forms of `é` and when `&eacute;` is pasted as **plain text**... No, **TextEdit** will not convert it to `é`.

Either copy from a source that show it as `é` or use the **Find and Replace...** *command* in **TextEdit** to find `&eacute;` and replace it with `é`.

---

As a side note, `&#233;` and `&#xE9;` also represent `é` in HTML.